# Does SFMC support fixed width imports

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does SFMC support fixed width when importing in to a data extension. It supports csv, tab, other

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can import into a Data Extension with a single column and parse out the individual columns using a [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) with the [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) SQL function.  It's not elegant, but it can be done.

Comment: So you could do something like this then. Select substring(cid,0,11) as customer_number, substring(name,11,30) as name from input_table. The cid being 11 digits long would this work?

Comment: Yes but you'd do the substring off of the entire row for every row, e.g. `select substring(entireRow,0,11) as customer_number, substring(entireRow,11,30) as name from input_table`

Comment: Thanks for this. how do i import it to a single column as its erroring?

Comment: I have now managed to import the file now